# How Handle Error in dpkg-repack

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

i want use dpkg-repack for many List of Packages(includes Error Missing Packs ..)
suppose there is 3 Packs A B C
A has Error (i.e not fully installed)
if i use:

```
dpkg-repack A , B , C
```

Bang Error ...
it don't Let Create B and C that is Correct
but if i use

```
dpkg-repcak B,C,A
```

create B.deb C.deb then Error

Now: How Can ignore Error packs and continue Likes for loob in java

```
for (i:)
{  dpkg-repack ...
   if error Continue; //ignore and Next packages

}
```

My Goal : i want create Backup from installed packages for use later offline if reinstall linux os

some packages may not installed or names not correct or installed incomplete
i use some command to get packages and his dependencies to txt file AND THEN
CALLED `dpkg-repack $(cat list.txt)` 
it starts to make deb file from list...
everything is good But if even one package name in list incorrect dpkg-repack stoped, it show error and don't let create deb file for remain names in list ..i want ignore bad names and continue to make deb file for other name.. 
i thinks its cleary my Goal (another way question : how use dpkg-repack for group list without stop when occur error??)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a simple bash script. Run this in the terminal:

```
for package_name in $(cat list.txt); do dpkg-repack $package_name; done;
```

This will iterate each word in `list.txt` and pass it in `package_name` variable. It will perform code inside the for loop and will not stop even dpkg-repack fails.